# Mongoosejs set/save vs. update for validation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I created some `schema.pre('save', function(){...});` validation, but then learned updates didn't trigger it.  I really wanted the validation on updates, so I started doing this:

```
MySchema.findOne({...}, function(doc) {
  doc.set(req.body);
  doc.save(function(){...});
});
```

Is there any downside to doing this?  It *seems* logical, but I haven't seen updates done this way as many times as I have seen them done with `doc.update({});` or `MySchema.findXxxAndUpdate({},{})`.  I realize `update` just passes everything through to the native driver, so set/save would incur some performance-penalties?  How about atomicity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main downside to your approach is that you lose atomicity of your updates, because another update can occur in-between the time of your `findOne` call and the call to `doc.save`.

You also lose the power of the various update operators like `$addToSet` that provide tested logic that you would otherwise have to implement in code.

Comment: Mongoose wraps each `save` operation with atomic `update` operation. It also have build-in versions support to prevent documents from being overwritten.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny Based on [this doc](http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning) the versioning is only used when updating embedded array properties, but it's not documented very well so you might be right that it does more than that.  Regardless, you'd still have to add code to handle the failed save case which can be messy.

Comment: As your link suggests, mongoose versions protects all array operations which may alter absolute positions of elements. All other update operations should works the same with `save` and `findOneAndUpdate`, except for getters, validators and hooks, because `mongoose` newer calls mongoidb `save` method. Fetching the whole document from db, updating the single field and saving it will result in atomic `update` operation on this field alone.

Comment: The only exception is `$inc` update operation, because mongoose can't perform it atomically during the `save` operation. The special [mongoose-number](https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-number) datatype was created for this case, but it's buggy.